# Why the conversion of an NFA to DFA is useful?

Tags: theory, dfa, nfa

Can someone tell me some reasons why the conversion of an NFA to DFA is useful?
Until now I have found the following reasons (I am not sure of them):

1. DFAs are faster than the NFAs
2. DFAs are easier to implement

Does anyone know another reason why this conversion is useful?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55287/convert-from-dfa-to-nfa#comment126030_55303

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-we-need-to-convert-from-NFA-to-DFA

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Answer (score 0):

> DFAs are faster than the NFAs

Yes and no.

On the one hand a given DFA of course runs "faster" than a given NFA, as an algorithm running an NFA needs to resolve the non-determinism in some way (e.g. by building the powersets at runtime).

On the other hand no: A DFA that is equivalent to a NFA will also likely be quite a lot bigger than the NFA, especially when derived by the NFA using powerset construction. This way the runtime of both will be pretty much the same.

But I'd argue that is pretty much besides the point here. We are talking about abstractions of computation we use to solve *theoretic* problems. We never implement a DFA on a "real" computer, so be don't really need to worry about speeds.

> DFAs are easier to implement

This is a bit confusing. Do you mean it is easier to come up with a DFA that does X than an NFA that does X? I heavily disagree with this, sometimes NFAs are the better tool to tackle a problem than a DFA, sometimes a DFA is enough.

If you mean it is easier to implement an algorithm that runs those automatas you are right, for a DFA you simply follow the transition function.

---

Back to your main question. Why convert?

In short: If you want to run an NFA, you have to remove the non-determinism, else a deterministic algorithm can't execute it. The question is who does it. An algorithm that can run NFAs will do that for you, if you don't have that tool at hand you need to convert it beforehand.

Comment: "*We* never implement a DFA on a "real" computer, so be don't really need to worry about speeds" --Not true, in my case.  I was able to reduce the CPU usage of a regex by removing backtracking which is basically equivalent to converting a DFA into an NFA.  ReDoS (REgular expression Denial Of Service) issues (including those that can take down production routers) have also been mitigated with this method (again, by me).  So, I guess I'm not included in this "We"  :-)

Comment: You took theoretical computer science, and used it in practice. That's illegal.

Comment: Are compilers theoretical? Is Regex theoretical? Complex numbers are theoretical, but you can harness their useful properties to get a Real (in the mathematical sense) number with real applications. In a similar vein, you can use the properties of NFAs and DFAs, implement an algorithm in code, and use the results in real applications. I don't know where this "real" computer talk comes from